# Can I use Ubuntu 18.04 Screen sharing with vino with Mac OS X Mojave Screen Shareing

Tags: networking, 18.04, macosx, tightvncserver, vino

I've set up Screen sharing on my Ubuntu 18.04, and VPN'd into my network remotely from my Mac. However when entering the correct vnc://... from Screen Sharing on my Mac, I get a message saying that the software on the remote machine is incompatible with this version of Screen Sharing on Mojave. However I've read online that this works. I've had tons of issues with TightVNC, just couldn't get it to work, kept on getting grey screens no matter what I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I just had to disable encryption.

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

As a bonus note, you can check the value of require-encryption via the command:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino | grep encrypt
```

To know more, this site is helpful: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-remote-desktop-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling encryption didn't work for me using Ubuntu 18.04 and macOS Mojave. I still get the error `The software on the remote computer appears to be incompatible with this version of Screen Sharing.`

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from somewhere.

1. First make sure Desktop Sharing is set up properly.
2. Download dconf-tools by typing in Terminal sudo apt-get install
   dconf-tools
3. Run dconf-editor
4. Expand org
5. Expand gnome
6. Expand desktop
7. Select remote-access
8. Uncheck require-encryption (don't click on Set to Default as it
   rechecks it)
9. Exit dconf-editor

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. "Quoting from somewhere" from somewhere is not what I would call a trusted source. Have you tried these step? Do they work? Why are the needed to fix that problem?

Comment: Highly underrated answer. Been searching for this for a long time! Fwiw, dconf-tools isn't available anymore, but this answer has a workaround. https://askubuntu.com/a/1296114/602762. Then run `dconf-editor` instead.